# How can I find filenames that do not have a . in them?

Tags: regex, filenames

**How can you find files by the following regex?**

```
[^.]
```

The solution may be in the commands: find, perl, ls

Comment: If you already know what commands would do this for you, why aren't you reading their manpages?  I think you pasted this question wholesale out of your homework, and you can't even be bothered to read the question.

Comment: @Sinan, perhaps anon's professors give good homework questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's about filename, like Greg thinks, then I'd suggest

```
find . -type f -not -name \*.\*
```

command instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -MFile::Find -le 'find sub { print if -f and /[^.]/ }, "."'
```

This will look in the current directory and all subdirectories for files that don't have a period in them.

Answer (score 2):

```
ls | grep -v \\.
```

You may have to be more specific in stating your question if this doesn't satisfy your requirements.

Comment: That will find directory names as well.